# Java read pptx file

Tags: java, powerpoint

Can someone help me how to read pptx file in java?i would prefer if this can be read with apache POI, i have been searched this tutorial but i can't find it.I've been successfully read the ppt file with this code :

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
    HSLFSlideShow show = new HSLFSlideShow(fs);
    SlideShow ss = new SlideShow(show);
    Slide[] slides=ss.getSlides();
    for (int x = 0; x < slides.length; x++) {
        System.out.println("Slide = " + (x + 1) + " :" + slides[x].getTitle());

        TextRun[] runs = slides[x].getTextRuns();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
            TextRun run = runs[i];
            if (run.getRunType() == TextHeaderAtom.TITLE_TYPE) {
                System.out.println("Slide title " + (i + 1) + ": " + run.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Slide text run " + (i + 1) + ": "  + run.getRunType() + " : " + run.getText());
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone tell me what part of this code must be modified to read pptx file?

Comment: You said above that you could "successfully read the pptx" file with the above posted code. Then you say "what part of this code be modified to read pptx" ?!?

Comment: do you know the different between ppt and pptx?

Comment: hmm.apologies. i did'nt read the post properly  i guess.

Comment: no problem, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html you need to use a separate set of classes to read OOXML .pptx files. There's example code in the cookbook: http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html

Comment: in the example, it's just explain how to read but only to append a slide on that file, not how to read the entire slide and show it to user.

Comment: When you have a XSLFSlide object you can use .getShapes() to get all shapes in the slide. If the shape is a XSLFTextShape you can use .getTextType() to check if it's a title, .getTextParagraphs() to get the paragraphs and .getTextRuns() on the paragraphs to get the text runs with the text. That should give you similar output to the code in your question.

Comment: can you give me some example how to use XSLFTextShape? i have try the .getShape() method and i print it in console but i receive this [Lorg.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFShape;@3632112e as the result.

Comment: You have to use casting as in the example code. See the lines near instanceof XSLFTextShape.

Answer (score 3):

Following link gives the complete code to read data from ppt... 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/DataExtraction.java

To provide a brief summary I can note the steps: 
First create the slide object using

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("url of your ppt"));
```

Get List of Sides in your ppt using:

```
final List<XSLFSlide> slide = ppt.getSlides();
```

Iterate through the slides and get a list of shapes in each slide using:

```
List<XSLFShape> shapes = selectedslide.getShapes();
```

Check the type of shape, it should be either XSLFTextShape or XSLFPictureShape. 
Then you can process and display the data accordingly.

Here is a link for further reading about shapes.
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFShape.html

The response by  @Arne de Bruijn
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to apache poi release notes, version 3.8 can be used to read PPTX. You have to check out the documentation though.

Comment: I'm using poi version 3.8 but i think it's very difficult to me to understands the documentation in reading pptx file.