# read .pptx causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, xslf

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684526/java-read-pptx-file) someone had a similar problem I have: I want to read the content of a .pptx file (only the text), but only got it work with .ppt files. So I tried to solve it with the accepted answer, but I got this exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hslf.model.TextPainter$Key`

I used the example from [this page](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html) (which was suggested in the accepted answer) so I have no idea why it does not work. My code:

```
public static String readPPTX(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream(path));
    String content = "";
    XSLFSlide[] slides = ppt.getSlides();
    for (XSLFSlide slide : slides){
        XSLFShape[] sh = slide.getShapes();
        for (int j = 0; j < sh.length; j++){
            if (sh[j] instanceof XSLFTextShape){
                XSLFTextShape shape = (XSLFTextShape)sh[j];
                content += shape.getText() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: You are missing some jar files. Add all jar files provided with Apache POI to your class path. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15106801/4720017

Comment: I have all these jar files mentioned there (it's a maven project)

Comment: I believe the jar file is poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar. Clean and build your project and try again maybe. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: ah, with scratchpad it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to this issue is to add the poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar file to the classpath of the project.